# Bristleback interaction with abilities and effects that doesn't have explicit direction

Tags: dota-2

How does Bristleback (ability) of Bristleback (hero) interacts with such damage sources:

- Cleave damage from attacks
- Damage-over-time (Venomancer's poison string, Viper's Corrosive Armor, Jakiro's Liquid Fire etc)
- Spells that doesn't have flying projectile (Luna's Lunar Beam is likely to strike from heaven not from Luna to target, Zeus's Thundergod's Wraith etc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The skill Bristleback is pretty straightforward. At any given time :

- If you are facing the source (understand the hero) of the damage : **you don't get reduced damage**
- If you're not facing the source of the damage : **you get reduced damage**.

It's not the projectile or the animation of the skill that matters but the position of the enemy hero and your position toward him. If Zeus casts Thundergod's Wrath at the other side of the map but you're not looking in his direction, you get reduced damage. As for damage over time, the same rule applies **but separately for every ticks  of damage**. If you decide to man up and fight the Venomancer after he casted Poison Nova but realise you are undergoing way too much damage, you can litteraly turn your back on that fight in order to reduce the amount of damage taken from the DoT.

Comment: Bristleback OP.

Comment: @RayofCommand [How do you counter Bristleback](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/150895/how-do-you-counter-bristleback/150914#150914) :D

Comment: yes it's more or less clear, but once he got his vanguard it feels as if he has already a heart :D

Comment: Best practice, pick bristle yourself ;) That's what I do